# Windows error report

Tags: windows

Found a lot of errors such as:  System archived Windows Error Report

I can't find the site that this info was on, but should it be reported to HP, my computers support or ATT, my service provider, or to Microsoft, my operating system?  Or just let it go?

Answer (score 0):

These are safe to delete.  They are just letting you know an error occurred and it was stored.

Check out this previous question for some more information: [Archived and Queued Windows Error Reporting](https://serverfault.com/questions/21777/archived-and-queued-windows-error-reporting)

You will want to investigate the errors though.